# Add a custom Style to SharePoint Foundation 2010

Tags: css, item-styles

I want to add a small snippet of CSS code to create a text block in SharePoint Foundation 2010, so when users are creating pages, they can highlight a block of text and use the dropdown to add the style to it.  Where do I go about doing this?  Google just gets me adding themes, which are way beyond the scope of what I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

I found this URL which was able to provide me with an answer:  http://sharepointroot.com/2010/05/28/adding-styles-to-ribbon-in-sharepoint-2010/